# Voiceover Recording Equipment

Tags: home-studio

I'm in the earliest stages of starting a 2nd career as a voice professional, and will be working from my home office.

The work involves bidding on, and accepting voice-over jobs from commercial, corp, and private sector clients; the work could entail doing web-page greetings, product descriptions, instruction manuals, event narrations, etc.

I'll be sending protected samples of my voice as resumes, in order to win jobs, and I don't want to use a paying studio. I've explored a few web pages, but have no clue what to purchase first, or any idea of exactly what I need. (Digital voice recorders, microphones, mixers, etc.)

Q&A: (5)
1. What Software Do I need?
2. What Hardware Do I need?
3. What should I know about sending the high-quality recordings to potential employers?
4. Are there recording professionals in this forum who can be hired, or consulted?
5. Are their other resources available for operating a recording studio from my home/pc?

Answer (score 2):

This is four or five questions in one so it's hard to provide a complete answer.  My knowledge can only help you with the technical question, so here it is as an answer anyway.

**Hardware:** At a minimum, you'll need a microphone, a preamplifier for the microphone, and some kind of audio interface to record it all, assuming you want to use your pc.  Most recording-targeted interfaces have preamplifiers built in, which is convenient, although you may want a more specialized sound from a dedicated preamp.  The choice of microphones is an art unto itself, although in my (limited) personal experience, a nice condensor through a tube preamp and a bit of dynamic range compression sounds very nice for general spoken voice.

**Software:** The free and simple wave recorder/editor **Audacity** is probably going to fulfill your needs splendidly.  If you need some feature it doesn't have, you can look into more specialized tools like DAW software, of which there is a ton.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Warrior Bob about having a separate microphone and pre-amp. I go both ways as far as recording on your PC - and old, cranky PC can mess up a recording as well, and for single and double track work, a small, dedicated digital recorder can be a real life saver. Plus it gives you the option of recording in the field.

I like the [Zoom H4n](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h4n/) but its a bit pricey for a basic set up. I also own an [M-Audio Micro Track II](http://www.m-audio.com/index.php?do=products.family&ID=MTII) which is less expensive.

Both those digital recorders have good built-in pre-amps, support a pair of phantom power microphones and removable digital media (SD or CF)... you can still use Audacity for editing, but you stop worrying about a virus scan or flaky driver on your PC messing up your recording.

As far as microphones are concerned, for what you're describing, a large diaphragm condensor microphone will give you a nice rich voice tone. It doesn't have to be hugely expensive, an Audio-Technica AT2020 is about a hundred bucks and sounds great. They do require a decent stand and pop filter though.

One other thing I'd add to the equation if you're serious about making good quality audio recordings - you probably don't have or want a full sized recording booth, you can dramatically improve the quality of your recordings with some sound-deadening gear.

I have a [RealTrap Portable Vocal Booth](http://www.realtraps.com/p_pvb.htm) which sits behind my microphone and stops the bulk of reflected sound.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The [VO-BB forums](http://www.vo-bb.com/phpBB2/) were very helpful when I needed to produce some training videos. There are a lot of pros handing out free advice on that site. The biggest thing I've learned is that technique and practice is much more important than gear.

I spent about $350 on a Studio Projects B1, Presonus AudioBox USB, cable, stand and pop filter. It does everything I need it to do and there are professional voiceover artists that got started with less than that.

Answer (score 0):

As a sofware there is a lot of different brands on the market, depens on your budget ofcourse. To get the professional sound you'll need a good sound card with mic preamps. As Warrior Bob mentioned you can use seperate preamp too.

In my recording mobile setup pack i use RME Fire Face UC sound card wich has fantastic sound, classic Rode NT 2000 mic, and a Dell Studio Laptop.My main recording DAW is Cakewalk Sonar Producer Edition. I usually record demo for the singers with this setup and very happy with it. This maybe can give you a little idea for what you looking for.Hope will be helpful for you. You can search from net there is thousand's of brands out there!